# Async await in node- 2 simultaneous awaits not getting executed

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, es6-promise

The code below only executes the first await can someone tell me what the problem is

```
const { readFile } = require("fs");

const getText = (path) => {
  return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
    readFile(path, "utf8", (err, data) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(data);
    });
  });
};
```

async await function

```
const start = async () => {
  try {
    const fir = await getText("./path/first.txt");
    const sec = await getText("./path/second.txt"); //not working !!!!!!!
    console.log(fir,sec);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

start();
```

output:

`hello this is the first text file`

The contents of second.txt are not displayed. On the contrary if I comment out the following line

`const fir = await getText("./path/first.txt");`

Then the contents of second.txt are displayed.

PS: The file paths are correct and the files are not empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the parameter order;

```
return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
```

...should be...

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

As it is now,

```
      else resolve(data);
```

...will due to the confused naming actually reject with the result and ending up logging just the error.